# ruby sinatra: "irb require" issue

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm discovering Sinatra and have started playing with it. All was just fantastic until the tutorial asks me to require a file in irb, so that the `Song` class is available to IRB:

```
irb> require './song'
```

I followed the tutorial to the letter, however, I keep getting the same error message below:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-doguria:views arnaud$ ls
about.slim  home.slim   not_found.slim  styles.scss
contact.slim    layout.slim song.rb
MacBook-Pro-de-doguria:views arnaud$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require './song'
/Users/arnaud/Google Drive/Code/codebasics/sinatra2/views/song.rb:1: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
SyntaxError: /Users/arnaud/Google Drive/Code/codebasics/sinatra2/views/song.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
DataMapper.s...rations'
                     ^
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from (irb):1
```

My file `song.rb` was copy pasted from the tutorial, and can be found below:

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
class Song
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :lyrics, Text
  property :length, Integer
  property :released_on, Date
end
DataMapper.finalize
```

- I tried both single and double quotation marks.
- I checked every single answer possible on Google, stack overflow, you name it.
- my file `song.rb` is in the right folder, I checked that, too.
- I deleted and re created the song.rb file twice, just to make sure it wasn't copy pasted.
- Other files are working fine, and the views I created are working perfectly.

As you can guess, I'm fairly new to programming, apologies in advance if it is something very basic that I overlooked.
Cheers.

Comment: I think there's an error in that file, we would need to see exactly what is at the top of the file

Comment: `require "./song"  => true` I can't reproduce it, so my best guess you are using Windows-style line endings? Oh and I'm really sure that `views` is not the right folder for your model (song.rb), but thats not related with your problem.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned above, I am really learning how to put ruby into practice, so essentially I'm following what my tutorial says (regarding the location of the song.rb file).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a problem with your file encoding.

Ruby shouts out a `SyntaxError` on line 1 of song.rb (read the error message carefully - it does not look as if line 1 would be what you want to be line 1), and complains about a stray `\r` in your but your `song.rb` file.

I assume you copy-pasted the code from somewhere into somewhere and these somewhere-applications did not behave cool.

Either you take on the journey to learn about file-encodings and conversions, or you find an option in your editor to save the file in the given encoding, or you re-copy the code into a new file and hope it just works(tm).

Comment: Actually, copying the code from the Question above back into the editor should resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions, much appreciated. 
Issue kind of sorted now, as I simply used another file name (ie. songs.rb instead of song.rb), which worked. As explained above, my first attempt was copy pasted, but I subsequently wrote the original code in a new file. Still don't know what happened, but that's how one learns I guess...